# How to move Drupal 8 site from Acquia Dev Deskto to Docksal?

Tags: localhost, drupal-8, migrate, acquia

Not sure where to ask this question. Not seeing any Docksal forums. I've found some limitations with Acquia's Dev Desktop app, so I'm trying the local version of a Drupal 8 website to Docksal.

I've successfully installed Docksal. I copied the existing site into a new folder. I'm at the point where the site loads - But, as a fresh install of Drupal. I "successfully" imported the existing database, but the site still loads like it's a new site to be set up. I've restarted Docksal, restarted the project, and restarted my computer. I looked through Docksal's help docs and found nothing.

I'm sure it's just some setting somewhere that needs to be changed, but I don't know what. For a rundown of what I did, I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1YIHtrMzZU

Comment: Yup - I've wasted two days on Docksal... about one day and 7 hours more than I should have.  

It it bazzar to find a so called tool wherein the only documentation that exists presumes that are starting a docksal project from something that already exists on Pantheon (or wherever). 

Why is there a "fin pull" . But no "fin push"

Why isn't there a shred of documentation describing how to import an existing Drupal 8 project (or any other project for that matter) into this so called tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Drupal installation. It is described in the docs https://docs.docksal.io/tools/drupal/